# Ionic 4 not creating an 'ios' folder in platforms after build

Tags: ionic4

Something very strange is going on with Ionic 4 cli.

If I remove the platforms folder and run a build command, like:

'ionic cordova build ios --aot --prod', Ionic is not adding a 'build' folder with the .ipa file.

I've removed and reinstalled ionic cordova.

Has anyone else run into this?????

Answer (score 0):

Below step helped me

In your Xcode, go to File -> Workspace Settings and in the first option select Legacy Build System if it is not selected:

Comment: Thanks Varun, I tired that. Same problem.